# Error Loading data into ElasticSearch using Azure Data Factory - Zappysys connector

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-data-factory

I was trying to load data from azure postgresql to elasticsearch through ADF copy activity using Zappysys connector.

Facing this issue.

```
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY＀㌀擿] Syntax error Ln 0, Col 68: Syntax error, expected: string, number, NULL, )
in: INSERT INTO "DATA"."Test" (name) VALUES (?),Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Exceptions.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY＀㌀擿] Syntax error Ln 0, Col 68: Syntax error, expected: string, number, NULL, )
in: INSERT INTO "DATA"."Test" (name) VALUES (?),Source=ZappySys API Driver,
'
```

I tried reducing the number of columns to one and imported schema under copy activity mapping to map the source and sink column but still got the same error.

Appreciate help in getting through this.

Comment: Hello gaurav, consider raising this issue with both the zappysys themselves and the adf team. If the odbc usererror is in fact pointing towards a syntax issue, they might be able to spot where the problem is, i am not aware of elasticsearch syntax, or zappysys so I cant help you here. it could be the third-party module maybe transfering your syntax in a wrong way, but I am not sure.  If zappysys is providing the odbc driver here, then its probably them who will know the answer.

Comment: Hello @ZiyaMertKarakas, thank you for the comment. Surely i will reach out to zappysys and adf team and post the resolution if i get any.